# Why can I request my local Arduino server by browser http, but not by my java Android-app http?

Tags: java, android, arduino, wifi

I am new in Android

I let a simple server run on my ArduinoMega answering requests for sensor data. If I request by any internet browser from LAN/WLAN/phone to the Arduino, I get an answer as I wanted.

But if I send an request from my Android app (Android studio/java/okhttp3) I get no answer from the Arduino server. It is like the server does not check that there is a client knocking.

If I request any internet site by my Android app, I get answer from that site

I get no error code.

My ideas are
a. Maybe I can not use the local IP as URL like I can do in the internet browser
b. Maybe Android needs for the LAN another permission as "INTERNET"
c. http/https problem?

The Arduino code

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
byte mac[]   = ...
byte ip[]      = { 192, 168, 178, 123 };                  // IP-Adresse
byte gateway[] = { 192, 168, 178, 1 };                    // Gateway
byte subnet[]  = { 255, 255, 255, 0 };
EthernetClient client;
EthernetServer server(80);
...
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet);
  server.begin();
...
client = server.available();         
  if (client) {
```

the app doesn't pass the last "if", so i think the server doesn't receive a request.

the java code

```
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
...
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextViewResult;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        String url ="http://192.168.178.123";

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mTextViewResult.setText(myResponse);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If i change the local IP to an URL, i get an answer from the server of that URL.

Comment: What is your IP address on your Android device? Is it in the same subnet?

Comment: The Android and the Arduino device have their own IP and are in the same subnet.